# Justification for phrase "[actor] is [character]"

Tags: grammar, expressions

Why is an actor's role commonly stated as

> Jim Carrey is Truman!

Why isn't it one of the following?

> Jim Carrey acts as Truman!
>
> Jim Carrey portrays Truman!

Why is the *is* of identity used when it clearly isn't the case.

Comment: To be fair, all three are commonly used.

Comment: "[actor] *as* [character]" is pretty common.

Comment: Justification?  Likely at least 1000 years of usage.

Comment: You ask “Why is the is of identity used when it clearly isn't the case?” The problem is that your assumption is simply wrong. Consider 2 + 2 is 4… clearly if there is a sign that has “2 + 2” on it, and someone asks “What is on the sign?” You do not reply “4”, do you? The “is” is the is of equivalence.

Comment: We have to use *some* verb. And so that's what we do. If we used a different verb, you'd be wondering the same thing about that other verb. (Why do we say "Jim Carrey portrays Truman? He isn't even holding a brush! It makes no sense at all.")

Answer (score 2):

With the most common acting method taught today (Sanford Meisner’s method,) the emphasis is on *authenticity* of action and reaction. In this school of thought, there is no character, just simply lines of dialogue on a page, and the “character” (if acted “authentically”) is nothing more than the actor’s genuine reactions to the words and actions in the scene and the world of the [screen]play. This “method acting” theory is somewhat different from the older school of character-acting thought from Konstantin Stanislavsky; that the actor *inhabits* and *portrays* a character which is *other* than himself, by imagining the set of “given circumstances” in which that character exists, and play-pretending to be under those circumstances, himself.

Within that acting industry context, it is often considered somewhat pejorative —or even downright insulting of their work— to say that an actor’s work is a “portrayal” or that he or she is “playing” a role, rather than being “authentic” and “present” in the role.

You’ll also commonly hear acting teachers and coaches use the highly critical feedback on an actor’s work, “stop acting.” (Meaning: “you’re being inauthentic and presentational, rather than naturally, authentically yourself.”)

Comment: To me this feels like justification in hindsight. It suggests that English-speaking actors are worth their salt, but in all the other languages where you don't — or indeed plain *can't* — say "Jim Carrey is Truman", all their actors are rubbish.

Comment: I don’t understand why anyone would take that negative implication about actors speaking other languages, but I admittedly have no experience with actor training in other languages or knowledge of the way those languages’ film credits are displayed... However, wasn’t the original question pertaining to why it is said this way *in English*?

Answer (score 0):

One might apply your objection to your own question: not many actors are named “Jim Carrey”, so it isn’t common at all to state that an actor’s role as “Jim Carrey is Truman!” You might occasionally have “Harrison Ford is Han Solo” and the like, but it is clear enough that you intended your quote to merely act as a pattern of sorts.

English tends to be quite free with metaphors, figures of speech, and generalisations etc, to the point that “is” has a fairly broad semantic range.

Here are a few examples we take for granted in everyday speech:

- The queen’s face is on the postage stamp (even if the Queen is in England and the stamp is in Nigeria).
- John flew on Qantas (even though Qantas is just an abbreviated company name).

Naturally, this introduces a huge amount of ambiguity, but context is usually enough for such phrases to be understood in the manner intended.

Answer (score 0):

While the most obvious sense of 'be' to be deduced here is 'have identity with' [[M-W 1b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be)] or 'comprise' [[Macmillan sense 3, saying what they are/consist of](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be)]:

- a glutton is a wolverine
- the scaffolding is steel

[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/be) includes the broadened metaphorical sense others have mentioned (and it is enormously broadened, almost all metaphors using 'be'. One wonders if this sense should be included in definitions at all.)

> **be** [v] ...
>
> **5.** Used as a copula in such senses as ... **e.** To seem to consist or be made of:
>
> - *The yard is all snow.*
> - *He is all bluff and no bite.*

"He is no Arthur" is a snowclone that doesn't stretch logic, though it combines the identity / make-up senses with the metaphorical.

"Clark Gable ***is*** Rhett Butler", complete with stress, is a famed expression showing many people's opinion that Gable had nailed the part in the film 'Gone with the Wind'.

The stress is perhaps at least partly because the expression 'X is Y', in acting, had become commonplace even at the time of the film.

Answer (score 0):

When an actor commits themself to a role, they can "play" the role where you see the actor's personality in the character or they can "be" the role where they seem to be a character totally separate from the actor's personality.

[Johnny Depp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Depp) is an example of an actor who, in my opinion, throws himself completely into his roles. I don't see anything in common between Captain Jack Sparrow (Pirates of the Caribbean), Edward Scissorhands, *Peter Pan* author J. M. Barrie (Finding Neverland), Ichabod Crane (Sleepy Hollow), and Frank Tupelo (The Tourist).

On the other hand, British comedic actor [Harriet Thorpe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harriet_Thorpe) (The Brittas Empire, Absolutely Fabulous, Alexei Sayle's Stuff, A Bit of Fry and Laurie, etc.) always has a large part of her own personality in each of her characters. I like her acting, but I don't consider it as "real" as Johnny Depp's.

To sell the illusion that we're watching real people living real lives, instead of a scripted story with actors pretending to be other people, the verb "to be" is used no matter what the actor's method is. In your example, I find most of Jim Carrey's characters to be very similar. However, studio executives want to sell his films by saying "Jim Carrey *is* Truman!", and the like.

Wiktionary gives one definition of "[to be](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be#Verb)" as:

> (*transitive*, *copulative*) *Used to indicate that the subject plays the role of the predicate nominal*
>
> - *François Mitterrand **was** president of France from 1981 to 1995.*

This meaning also fits an actor playing the role of a character. Jim Carrey was Truman in *The Truman Show*.